# Change the selectedindex of a select element generated using js not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the selected value of a select html element that was created using the js function createElement(), but for some reason the selected index stays the same even if i change it. Here's the code:

```
            let vendor_cell = document.createElement("td");
            let vendor_dropdown = document.createElement("select");
            vendor_dropdown.setAttribute("id", "selectID" );

            for (let vendorID in vendors) { //generates options using vendors array.
                let option = document.createElement("option");
                option.value = vendorID;
                option.text = vendors[vendorID];
                vendor_dropdown.add(option);

            }
            document.getElementById("selectID").selectedIndex = "3";

            vendor_cell.appendChild(vendor_dropdown)
            row.appendChild(vendor_cell);
```

I've noticed that the id im assigning isn't showing up when I inspect the page on my browser.

Comment: Why do you set selectedIndex to “3” instead of 3?

Comment: I was just trying different things to see if it would work. I originally had it as 3, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Could it be that you haven't actually added the element, that you created, to the DOM prior to trying to find it with `getElementById`? You can't find what is not there yet.

Comment: I've tried putting the getElementById line all over my table generation function, including the very end, but that still didn't change anything. The table contains this select element as a cell.

Comment: Have you tried `vendor_dropdown.selectedIndex = 3;`?

Comment: yes, it still doesn't change.

Comment: what is vendor array exactly ? could you add a sample?

Comment: it looks like this: var vendors = {};
     vendors[1] = "Acer";
     vendors[2] = "HP";
     vendors[3] = "MARCONI INSTR";
     vendors[4] = "ALESSI IND";
the options appear for the select element, but they dont change when i try to do it through js. They do change when i manually do it on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Wil you try that ?

```js
const 
  row             = document.querySelector('table tr')
, vendor_dropdown = row.insertCell().appendChild( document.createElement('select') )
  ;
var vendors = 
  { '1': 'Acer'
  , '2': 'HP'
  , '3': 'MARCONI INSTR'
  , '4': 'ALESSI IND' 
  } 

Object.entries(vendors).forEach(([key,val]) =>
  { 
  vendor_dropdown.add(new Option(val,key,(key==3),(key==3)))
  })
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For info:

```
for (let vendorID in vendors) { 
  option.value = vendorID;
  option.text = vendors[vendorID];
```

is not a problem...

```js
var vendors = 
  { '1': 'Acer'
  , '2': 'HP'
  , '3': 'MARCONI INSTR'
  , '4': 'ALESSI IND'     // --> index value is 3
  } 
  
for (let vendorID in vendors)
  {
  console.log( vendorID, '-->', vendors[vendorID] )
  }
  
console.log('\n------- or  (same result) :')

Object.entries(vendors).forEach(([key,val]) =>
   console.log( key, '-->', val ))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

> *"From what i can see, the id i'm assigning for the select element isn't actually being assigned."*

I marked the areas with a ✳️ concerning the `<select>`.

***Details are commented in example***

```js
/*
It's not very clear as to what type of data you are using.
This is an object with nested objects. It's horrible for
iteration (iterating is 80% of our code). If this isn't
the data type let me know.
*/
const vendors = {
  "0":{"id":"68084-610","name":"Brainlounge"},
  "1":{"id":"52125-271","name":"Midel"},
  "2":{"id":"49349-907","name":"Cogilith"},
  "3":{"id":"52959-187","name":"Voolia"},
  "4":{"id":"36987-3319","name":"Thoughtstorm"},
  "5":{"id":"54569-3302","name":"Innojam"}
};
// Get an array of vendors values and flatten 1 array
let data = Object.values(vendors).flat();
console.log(data)
// Added a <form>                 ✳️
const form = document.forms[0]; //✳️
// Reference all form controls    ✳️
const IO = form.elements;       //✳️
// Find the first row of the <table>
const row = document.querySelector('table').rows[0];
// Create <td> and <select>
let cell = document.createElement("td");
let dropdown = document.createElement("select"); //✳️
/*
iterate through data array        ✳️
- Create a <option>               ✳️
  - add id from array to .value   ✳️
  - add name from array to .text  ✳️
  -add <option> to <select>       ✳️
*/
for (let vendor of data) {                       //✳️
  let option = document.createElement("option"); //✳️
  option.value = vendor.id;                      //✳️
  option.text = vendor.name;                     //✳️
  dropdown.append(option);                       //✳️
}

// Add <select> to <td>, add <td> to <tr>
cell.append(dropdown);
row.append(cell);
// Assign [name] to <select>                             ✳️
dropdown.name = 'vendorList';                          //✳️
// Referencing <select> by forms and .elements properties✳️
IO.vendorList.selectedIndex = '3';                     //✳️
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 2px ridge grey
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I should have clarified this, but the vendor array is actually from the database(phpmyadmin). The vendorID is used to get the vendor that is associated with that ID. I have a function that gets the vendor details from the db that executes before all of the given code.

Comment: Could you post an example of what the data looks like after it is processed from the db and before it is rendered in the DOM?

Comment: there is no porblem with `for (let vendorID in vendors)`

Comment: So the data structure resembles the one in your answer?

Comment: sorry for the late answer. I dont think the problem lies in the vendors array, as all the data shows up the way it should in the page. From what i can see, the id i'm assigning for the select element isn't actually being assigned. When i inspect the page on my browser, the select element just shows up as <select>whatever</select> with no attributes.

Comment: also just to clarify, this is the fuction i use to get vendors from the database:                                        ``` $db = new Database();
$query_string = 'SELECT * FROM vendors WHERE vendorID=? LIMIT 1;';
$db->query($query_string, 'i', $vendorID);
$vendor = $db->get_result(singular: true);
$db->close();

return $vendor; ```

Comment: I no not the sorcery of the back-end. I am a wizard of the front-end 

Comment: @AsfandSalamAlavi I marked the steps taken to create and populate the `<select>` in my [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72624281/2813224)

Comment: unfortunatly that didn't change anything.  The one thing I'm having difficulty understanding is that why the id im assigning isnt being assigned.

Comment: How did you add my code because the only requirement it needs that OP might not have is a `<form>`. Do you have a single `<form>` wrapped around everything? Having a `<form>` establishes some very old but stable and very standard interfaces. If you followed my code and couldn't get it working then it's probably how the data is structured and the `for...in` is failing. My code works perfectly, the only aspect of it that I'm not 100% sure about is what the real data looks like.